# Jetty :: ServletContextHandler#setContextPath(..) and how to associate Servlets with specific file extensions

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, contextpath

I have the following code in [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/):

```
ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
contextHandler.setContextPath("/a");
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(MyServlet.class);
contextHandler.addServlet(holder, "/b/*");
```

what is the difference between `"/a"` in the call to `setContextPath` and `"/b/*"` in the call to `addServlet` ? Are these paths concatenated to decide which requests `MyServlet` will serve?

Also, is it possible to associate a servlet with a specific file extension? I.e. by looking at the "`endsWith`" part, so to speak, of a URI and so dispatching URIs ending in, e.g. ".xsd" to a specific Servlet? Or is dispatching entirely based on "`startsWith`" logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should conform basically to the [servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), where an URL consists of `http://host:port/<context-root>/<servlet-path-spec>`, where the Context root is defined by `setContextPath` and the Servlet path specification is defined by the second parameter of `addServlet`. So the servlet in your example would serve all URLs starting with `http://host:port/a/b/`.

The Servlet path specification does also allow to define mappings to file extensions, with the notation "*.xsd" in your example, see section 12.2 in the linked specification.